# translate a data model to another and api call in Android

Tags: api, kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines, endpoint

I am trying to map a data class to another one but during the process I need to also place a call to get additionnal information

The code below is a basic call with coroutine

```
override suspend fun getUsersList(
    name: String?): ResultList<List<GitHubUserListResult>> =
    withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        val request = api.searchUsers(name)
        request.data --> contain the list of `User`
        
        //map User to GitHubUserListResult and place api all to recover the missing information
         
        ResultList.Success(emptyList()) --> will be the list of `GitHubUserListResult`
    }
```

The data class User is :

```
data class User (
    val login: String?,
    val avatar_url: String
)
```

the data class GitHubUserListResult:

```
data class GitHubUserListResult (
    val login: String?,
    val avatar_url: String,
    val public_repos: Int
)
```

`public_repos` required a new api call to `api.getUsernameInfo(username)` to recover the number of repos and then add it to `GitHubUserListResult`

`api.getUsernameInfo(username)` will return the data class below:

```
data class UserInfo (
    val public_repos: Int
)
```

Any idea how to do this mapping and api call ?

Answer (score 0):

```
override suspend fun getUsersList(name: String?): ResultList<List<GitHubUserListResult>> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    val asyncJobs = api.searchUsers(name).map { user ->
       async { getGithubInformation(user) }
    }
    return ResultList.Success(asyncJobs.awaitAll())
}
```

You might have to include some logic for catching exceptions and convert to something like `ResultList.Error`

Comment: Thanks Robert the asyncJobs. only return List<Userinfo> not List<GitHubUserListResult>